# How do I make my header move in response to the height of the browser instead of a scroll bar appearing?

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://www.akaskyness.com/

This is in the early stages of development. I want this "cover" page to be non-scrollable, with the height of the white|black background adjusting to the height of the browser window. At the moment, when reducing the height of the browser window, the headers don't shift up proportionally and a scrollbar appears. I'm not really concerned about browser width at the moment because I haven't added any code for that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you mean - you want the `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements to shift vertically as the viewport height is resized, so that they don't end up off the screen (when it gets too short) and create a scrollbar.

In your current CSS, you try to do this using `margin-top:17%` on `<header>`. This seems like a logical approach, except something curious happens: the `margin-top` never changes, regardless of how you resize the browser vertically.

I'll be honest, this stumped me for a while, so I did some searching around about margin behaviour and found out [this critical piece of information](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties): *"The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block."* So the browser height is completely ignored in the calculation! If you resize the width of your browser, you can actually see how your headers move up and down on your webpage.

Well, that completely invalidates using a percentage margin to attempt to vertically align `<header>` relative to the viewport height. What now? Vertical alignment of elements is actually something lots of other developers have tackled in various ways. Here's a simple one that uses absolute positioning, by only rewriting the styles for `<header>`:

```
header {
  margin-top:-3em;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:50%;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Me2gD/1/) of this new CSS. Note that `margin-top:-3em;` is a bit of a guess on (half of) how tall your headers are, so if you don't want to hard-code that value, you'll probably have to look at a different approach for vertical alignment (this is just one of the easiest). Also, if you don't want it vertically centered, just change `top:50%;` to a different percentage value.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is the SECOND time you've helped me in the past several days. You're extremely helpful. You should just mentor me, haha.

Comment: Haha, no problem. This was fun for me too, since I got to learn something.